# first and last value of a Day in Pandas (Python)

Tags: python, date, pandas, timestamp

I have a long period of data (3 Month), which was logged every 15 seconds.

The first Timestamp looks like this: 2017-04-01 00:00:00
The lastTimestamp looks like this: 2017-04-01 23:59:45

Now i am looking for a way to get the first and the last value of the column "Temp".
It would be nice to have this two values in two new columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by `days` with aggregate by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.aggregate.html) [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.first.html) and [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.last.html):

```
N = 100000
rng = pd.date_range('2011-01-01', periods=N, freq='15S')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': rng, 'Temp': range(N)})  
#print (df)

df = df.resample('D', on='Timestamp')['Temp'].agg(['first','last'])
print (df)
            first   last
Timestamp               
2011-01-01      0   5759
2011-01-02   5760  11519
2011-01-03  11520  17279
2011-01-04  17280  23039
2011-01-05  23040  28799
2011-01-06  28800  34559
2011-01-07  34560  40319
2011-01-08  40320  46079
2011-01-09  46080  51839
2011-01-10  51840  57599
2011-01-11  57600  63359
2011-01-12  63360  69119
2011-01-13  69120  74879
2011-01-14  74880  80639
2011-01-15  80640  86399
2011-01-16  86400  92159
2011-01-17  92160  97919
2011-01-18  97920  99999
```

If `df` has `DatetimeIndex` omit parameter `on`:

```
N = 100000
rng = pd.date_range('2011-01-01', periods=N, freq='15S')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Temp': range(N)}, index=rng)  
#print (df)

df = df.resample('D')['Temp'].agg(['first','last'])
print (df)
            first   last
2011-01-01      0   5759
2011-01-02   5760  11519
2011-01-03  11520  17279
2011-01-04  17280  23039
2011-01-05  23040  28799
2011-01-06  28800  34559
2011-01-07  34560  40319
2011-01-08  40320  46079
2011-01-09  46080  51839
2011-01-10  51840  57599
2011-01-11  57600  63359
2011-01-12  63360  69119
2011-01-13  69120  74879
2011-01-14  74880  80639
2011-01-15  80640  86399
2011-01-16  86400  92159
2011-01-17  92160  97919
2011-01-18  97920  99999
```